# how to httpput the image on a remote server from android

Tags: java, android, image, http

I have tried with following code , but its not working

```
File file= new File(filename);
byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut put= new HttpPut(url);
for (int i = 0; i  pairs = new ArrayList();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Data", data));
put.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
```

I could not able to PUT the data on the server I have also tried with HttpsURLConnection but its getting uploaded.

Comment: Please define "it is not working". Also, is your Web server really expecting an HTTP PUT of a form that would ordinarily be used with POST?

Comment: the image is not getting uploaded path is there in "filename"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the content length I am able to do HTTP put , with the help of [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) as follows

```
https.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
https.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + file.length());
```